# Unload View Controller in TabBar application

Tags: ios, core-data, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an app that is using a Tab Bar.  My second view in the tab bar has 4 text inputs.  When the user hits the 'save" button I want the the input from the text inputs to save to core data (which I have done) and then for the first view to appear.  The first view has a table view which displays the data.  I have been able to accomplish this but when I go back to the second view, the previous input is still in the text fields.  Even worse, if I try to save this data again it seems like I am trying to save the same instance to core data.  My app crashes whenever I have more than one row in the tableview, and I believe it is because of this problem.

When I select "Save" on the second view, how do I get that view controller to unload so the next time I go to that view I start off with a clean instance?

Comment: You don't need to unload the view controller, just set the text of any text field's to nil. I'm not sure this is your problem though - saving the same data again should just create a second entity with the same content as the first, not cause a crash.